# Потоки C windows 10

Tags: c, windows, многопоточность, macos

Сразу признаюсь, что я новичок в данной теме, поэтому не судите строго)
Есть проблема с количеством потоков, которые создаются командой pthread_create.

```
void* write_data_in_memory(unsigned int* buffer){
pthread_t threads[D];
    unsigned int* start = buffer;
    int data_size = A/D;
    for(int i = 0;i<D-1;i++){
        multiply_set_buffer_args args = {data_size,start,i};
        printf("%d\n", i);
        pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,set_buffer,(void*) &args);
        start+=data_size;
    }
}
```

В данном методе создаются потоки, которые заполняют ячейку памяти рандомными числами. Количество потоков(D) равно 83.
Данная программа была запущена на двух машинах- macOS и windows. В первом случае никаких проблем обнаружено не было, и все 83 потока работают, однако на windows отрабатывают всего 32-33. Возможно есть какие то ограничения на количество потоков в windows или вообще проблема в коде(мб я не ту либу использую)?

Comment: Уточнение: один раз программа отработала нормально(все 83 потока отработали), в коде ничего не менял. Возможно проблема с тем, что недостаточно оперативной памяти?

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, не ту. В С++ библиотеке есть встроенная поддержка https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread

Пример использования:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
 
void f1(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Thread 1 executing\n";
        ++n;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
}
 
void f2(int& n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Thread 2 executing\n";
        ++n;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
}
 
class foo
{
public:
    void bar()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            std::cout << "Thread 3 executing\n";
            ++n;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        }
    }
    int n = 0;
};
 
class baz
{
public:
    void operator()()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            std::cout << "Thread 4 executing\n";
            ++n;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        }
    }
    int n = 0;
};
 
int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    foo f;
    baz b;
    std::thread t1; // t1 is not a thread
    std::thread t2(f1, n + 1); // pass by value
    std::thread t3(f2, std::ref(n)); // pass by reference
    std::thread t4(std::move(t3)); // t4 is now running f2(). t3 is no longer a thread
    std::thread t5(&foo::bar, &f); // t5 runs foo::bar() on object f
    std::thread t6(b); // t6 runs baz::operator() on object b
    t2.join();
    t4.join();
    t5.join();
    t6.join();
    std::cout << "Final value of n is " << n << '\n';
    std::cout << "Final value of foo::n is " << f.n << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Я прошу прощения, просто мне код на чистом C нужно, в тэгах плюсы случайно указал

Comment: @NuNDust уберите тогда метку